# makepkg without dependencies in archlinux

Tags: archlinux

How to use 'makepkg' in Arch Linux to install an AUR without installing any dependencies?
Or any AUR helper that could do that?

Somehow similar to pacman (packages) :

```
pacman -Sdd sompackage
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't this rather suited for SuperUser?

Comment: makepkg doesn't install anything. It only builds packages, which you install using pacman

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are looking for the `-d` option of makepkg.

> -d, --nodeps
>              Do not perform any dependency checks. This will let you override
>              and ignore any dependencies required. There is a good chance this
>              option will break the build process if all of the dependencies are
>              not installed.

If you use [Yaourt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Yaourt), you can use the `-d` option, it will be passed to makepkg.